# How to make check that user can only record video upto 30 sec in iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, video, camera

I'm recording video in iPad application it is working fine but problem is that I want that user can record video upto 30 seconds only any way to make user bound upto 30 seconds then show alert .

```
-(void)onHomeButtonClickVideo{

UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;

if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
   {
    NSArray *mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString*)kUTTypeMovie];
    picker.mediaTypes = mediaTypes ;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    picker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo ;
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:NO];
[picker release];
}
   else
    {   
    UIAlertView *alt=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@" Camera Facility is not available with this Device" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alt show];
    [alt release];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all make image picker object as property in .h file

the code like this

```
 -(void)onHomeButtonClickVideo{

picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;

if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])

   {
    NSArray *mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString*)kUTTypeMovie];
    picker.mediaTypes = mediaTypes ;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    picker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo ;
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:NO];

[self performSelector:@selector(stopCapturingVideoAfterSomeTime) withObject:nil afterDelay:30];

}

   else
    {


    UIAlertView *alt=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@" Camera Facility is not available with this Device" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alt show];
    [alt release];


}


-(void)stopCapturingVideoAfterSomeTime
{
   [picker stopVideoCapture];

 // what ever code you want at the time of video stop : show alert or any thing
}
```

Comment: it is working but what if user wants to take photo instead of video then

Comment: you need to check whether recording is start or not.

Comment: how i want that i have two button if user click on video then it should records as it is working and if click on take photo then it should take phot

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code

```
     UIImagePickerController* picker = .......
        picker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];
        picker.videoMaximumDuration = 30; //in seconds
        record.saveToAlbum = YES;
        [self loadCamScreensWithPicker:picker];

 NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
 NSData *data_Page = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];
 if (([data_Page length]/1024/1024)<=30) 
    {

       // Not Exceed 30 SEC
    }
    else{

       // Exceed 30 Seconds
    }
```